# Can't Refresh Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I've done it successfully about a month ago and now I can't. 
When I try to Refresh (keep my files), it runs and than after some time reboots, shows Undoing changes and when it is finished it informs me that it wasn't able to finish. 
Any ideas? I didn't do any changes to the system since the last time and I have 40-50GB free space.